Why adding network_mode: "host" doesn't let me inject data to database
I am trying to implement data ingestion pipeline, which should efficiently ingest stream of metrics into a PostgreSQL database.There should be two containers one for application another for db. Communication between the containers should be configured to occur through the network interface of the host machine on which the application is running.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file
docker-compose.yml
services:   app:
    build: .
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/metrics_db


    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: ["python" , "app.py"]

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: metrics_db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:   db_data:
    driver: local

Previously when I tested without network_mode: "host" I could inject data to my PostgreSQL database without running from container.But now when I added network_mode: "host" in order to satisfy requirement that two containers should communicate through host network  now I am getting
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5000: Connection refused

But when I run
docker exec -it data-ingestion-pipeline-app-1 /bin/bash

to go into container and inside that container I run same code data get's transferred to db. Can you help to understand why I can't inject data to db without running the code within container ?

You don't need network_mode: host in this setup and you should remove it.  You'll need to change the DATABASE_URL to use the Compose service name of the database as the host name, postgresql://...@db/....

The error you show (Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5000) has nothing to do with Postgres. That suggests that (a) you're trying to connect to your web app and that (b) the app has failed to start.

@DavidMaze so should be like this DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@db:5432/metrics_db?
Before it was like this, does this  require that communication between containers happens through host network? Because that's why I added network_mode: host

@larsks Ok so I am thinking it has to do with line *network_mode: host *? Because before adding this line app started successfully.

You should remove network_mode: host.  There's no particular need to disable Docker networking for this basic setup.

@DavidMaze Thanks so I am given assignment where I need to have containers communicate with each other using host network. With removing that line will problem description be fulfilled?

The network packets will not leave the physical machine, if that's your question.  If you remove network_mode: host then you will use Docker's standard networking layer, which is usually a best practice.
